# How to get two different results on startActivityforResult using click Listener from the same button?

Tags: android

I'm making an android app and I'm using `startActivityforResult` on click listener. So it is opening the other activity and from there, result will get back to the first activity. Now it is working perfectly. I have Three different buttons on second Activity so I wanted to send different result on different button-click and I have no idea how to do it using `startActivityforResult`.

```
      ll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
          //   startActivity(new 
              Intent(publishNewBook.this,selectionActivity.class));
              Intent i=new 
              Intent(publishNewBook.this,selectionActivity.class);
              startActivityForResult(i,1);
          }
      });
}
```

Content to be sent from these two buttons.

```
    l1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        Intent p = getIntent();

        int getSell=p.getIntExtra("but",0);

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (getSell==flg1) {
                Intent i = new Intent(fanfBook.this, Main.class);
                i.putExtra("BUY_URL", BUY_URL);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else{
               int first=1;
               Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
               returnIntent.putExtra("urlNovel", URL);
               returnIntent.putExtra("Novel", novel);
               returnIntent.putExtra("first",first);
               setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
               finish();
            }
        }
    });

    l2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        Intent p = getIntent();
        int getSell=p.getIntExtra("but",0);

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (getSell==flg1) {
                Intent i = new Intent(fanfBook.this, Main.class);
                i.putExtra("BUY_URL", BUY_URL);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else{
                Intent r2 = getIntent();
                r2.putExtra("urlBio", URL_BIO);
                r2.putExtra("bio", bio);

                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, r2);
                finish();
         }
     }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the content of result which you want to send?

Comment: wait i will post that code

Answer (score 0):

you should use on the first activity:
onActivityResult() and use the codes and data you've sent from the second activity

Answer (score 0):

When you send the data change the `REQUEST_CODE` for the 3 different intent call. like ->

```
int REQUEST_CODE_1 = 1010;

ll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(publishNewBook.this,selectionActivity.class);
            Intent(publishNewBook.this,selectionActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_CODE_1);


        }
    });
```

when you return from second activity you just check the REQUEST_CODE . Like ->

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_1){
            // so , do action for button 1 click back.
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry sir but it working for only one of return result not for two.

Answer (score 0):

[From](http://www.mybringback.com/android-sdk/12204/onactivityresult-android-tutorial/)  your main activity you call [startActivityforresult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) passing the intent you want to start and a requestcode uniquely marking this request,  starting activitytwo. In activitytwo you setresult passing resultcode and optionally an intent containing any data then call finish. Now mainactivitys onactivityresult callback method will be called giving requestcode, resultcode and the optional [intent](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) (or null in the case of no return data). The only confusion I can see is maybe you have two or more of these things in that case uniquely identify requestcode in each and "if" them or "switch case"